# Is it possible changle the final modifier of a field in a subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, immutability

The situation is this

```
class Immutable
{
    public final int myField;

    public Immutable(int value)
    {
        myField = value;
    }

    //methods that treat the object as immutable
}

class Mutable extends Immutable
{
    //no longer final. The same field. Not subclass hiding superclass field.
    public int myField;

    //more methods, these mutate the state of the object
}
```

Can this be done in Java? Or even a language extension? With casts and all.

Comment: You're hiding the field in the parent class, not replacing it; as such, you're not really "changing" it, but you can make the subclass field non-final. You just have to be very careful which one you are referring to: if you have `Immutable foo = new Mutable();` then `foo.myField` is the one from `Immutable`, not `Mutable`.

Comment: Note that `Immutable` isn't immutable, because it's not final.

Comment: @AndyTurner I don't want to hide the field of the superclass, and I know that's what this piece of code does, but since I don't know how to do what I want (1 field that's final in a superclass but not final in a subclass) I coded it like that, as an illustration.

Comment: @FinnTheHuman what you're actually asking for is completely 100% impossible.

Comment: @LouisWasserman there's not even some crazy language extension that allows that? I'm willing to pay the price and learn one of those

Comment: @FinnTheHuman what are you actually trying to do? I strongly suspect there is a better way to do this than breaking the language.

Comment: Nope, nothing.  No way at all.

Comment: @FinnTheHuman by language extension, do you mean a JVM language ?

Comment: @AndyTurner it's not required for a class to be final so to be immutable, having final methods is enough in most cases

Comment: I'm trying to have mutable and immutable versions of geometric objects, such as Vectors, BoundingBoxes, BoundingSpheres, Planes, Rays, ect.

Comment: @niceman I think I mean that... One of those languages... I think Scala is the name of one of them?

Comment: Just create a non-final field and don't allow your immutable class to modify it. Of course, you'll need to hide it behind a getter, which is good practice anyhow.

Comment: @shmosel that's one way of doing it, but as you can see, I declare my field as public.

Comment: So... maybe don't?

Comment: @FinnTheHuman those are called JVM languages, they aren't "extensions" to java, they are languages on their own

Comment: @niceman no, it's really not enough: if you can add mutability to a subclass, then you can't know if a reference to the superclass is the "mutable" or "immutable" version. The only way in which a non-final class can be immutable is if it has only private constructors.

Comment: @niceman so do you know any of those languages that would allow what I want?

Comment: @FinnTheHuman why do you want to have mutable and immutable versions of geometric objects ? for me it's reasonable for all of them to be immutable

Comment: @FinnTheHuman anyway you can define two versions of the superclass(`ImmutableObject` and `MutableObject`) and make it such that all inheriting from `ImmutableObject` are immutable and those inheriting from `MutableObject` are mutable

Comment: So there's no way of achieving what I asked, only alternatives. I know the alternatives, guys. Thank you all for commenting.

Comment: @FinnTheHuman that's how google guava's make immutable versions of java collections I believe :)

Comment: @AndyTurner A type could still be immutable if it's not final. Just don't allow subtypes to modify state

Comment: @VinceEmigh a superclass can't stop a subclass adding its own state.